# How can I rename the PDF file, with the URL from where I downloaded it using Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a List of links that I have collected from google search results and I'm downloading these  (PDF) files using selenium.

I want to rename each file so that its filename contains the URL.

What can I do?

I have not tried any code so please help me. I'm showing the code of selenium that I used to download the files.

```
folderName=input(("Enter The FolderName:\t")).upper() #Geting Input for the name of folder

newDir="C:\\Users\\sulta\\Data Science CV\\" + folderName
print(newDir)
if not os.path.exists(newDir):
    os.makedirs(newDir) #creating folder 
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
"download.default_directory":"C:\\Users\\sulta\\Data Science CV\\" + folderName, #Downloading the files to thi path
"download.prompt_for_download": False, #To auto download the file
"download.directory_upgrade": True,
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True #It will not show PDF directly in chrome
})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
for z in range(len(link)): #My All links are stored in the list named link
    try:
        driver.get(link[z])
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
    except:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

**I dont think there's any python core library that can do this on selenium download. What you can do is to have a folder watchdog that keeps track of any changes or events that occur in the folder so that you can the rename the new file from there.
Check out `pyWatch` it could be of help.**

Answer (score 0):

```
for z in range(len(link)): 
    try:
        driver.get(link[z])
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)

        # create the file name from the link, like below:
        file_name = link[z].replace("/", "-")

        # add the code to download the pdf file

        # rename the downloaded file
        os.rename('<downloaded file name with path>', file_name <with path>)
    except:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to read all the files on the directory, download the new file then read again to get its name and them rename it to what you want, something like this

```
folderName=input(("Enter The FolderName:\t")).upper() #Geting Input for the name of folder

newDir="C:\\Users\\sulta\\Data Science CV\\" + folderName
print(newDir)
if not os.path.exists(newDir):
    os.makedirs(newDir) #creating folder 
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
"download.default_directory":"C:\\Users\\sulta\\Data Science CV\\" + folderName, #Downloading the files to thi path
"download.prompt_for_download": False, #To auto download the file
"download.directory_upgrade": True,
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True #It will not show PDF directly in chrome
})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
for z in range(len(link)): #My All links are stored in the list named link
    try:
        import os
        files_before = os.listdir(newDir) #list all files
        driver.get(link[z])
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
        files_after = os.listdir(newDir) # list all files after download

        new_file = list(set(files_after) - set(files_before))[0] # get new file in folder
        new_name = 'new_name.file' #name of new file
        os.rename(newDir+'/'+new_file,newDir+'/'+new_name) #rename new file in path
        
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: It's Not as working as I want.. My question is this, can I rename the file that  I have downloaded by that link from where I downloaded it... Is it possible that the selenium work like this  --> Read a LInk from the list--> Download the File --> Rename the file by That link from Where I downloaded it --> than take next link from the list and repeate the same process Kinldy Think About this

Comment: You want the file with the same name as the link?
Changing the following line to this maybe?
new_name = link[z]

Comment: Yes I want to rename the file by its own URL that is stored in list named link

Comment: Did you tried the change I commented? new_name = link[z] ?

Comment: I tried But It's not Working As I want Can you try any other way please ?

Comment: Can you send me your code so i can take a look?

Comment: Yes Sure Please tell me how can I share it with you